# Matlab spectrogram, butter and filter functions questions

Tags: matlab, function, filter

1. how can i change the colors of the spectrogram to show more intense near to violet and less intense near to red?
2. How can i apply the butter and filter functions to the wav file to show:

   - a lowpass cutting frecuency of 4500hz
   - a bandstop with central fecruency of 3000 hz and bandwith of 1000 hz

and then show this filtered signals in a spectrogam?.

Comment: I think you can get the outputs of the spectrogram, namely [S,F,T,P]. You can make your own mesh plot using F and T (zeros for the z axis) and then specify a colormap that goes between red and violet. To show the effect of your filters all you have to do is filter the data then call the spectrogram again and plot again

Comment: whats the code for the filters?

Comment: the simple way to filter is to determine the filter coefficients using butter(), and then using the function filtfilt() to filter the data. For more advanced filters you can look at methods in the DSP toolbox

Comment: @willpower2727 `Filtfilt` will double the order and implements a zero-phase digital filter, so it's a tricky command for a beginner and is maybe not what he wants.

Comment: @Matt I'm not assuming Mr. Leyton is a beginner.

Comment: @willpower2727 He asks for help on how to design the filter and how to apply it. Therefore I assume he is new to DSP in Matlab. Please don't get me wrong, this is not meant in a negative way at all. My remark was just to raise attention, that `filtfilt` is maybe not what he expects of *applying* the filter.

Answer (score 1):

The following Matlab-code should do what you want. The arguments for the filter-design are defined as variables and can be changed to adjust the filter.
If you want the plots to be separated, just erase `subplot(3,1,x)` and put `figure` before `spectrogram`. Then you'll have three individual plots.

To use your `.wav`-file, delete the line which loads the sample data and uncomment the line with the `audioread`-command.

```
load('speech_dft.mat');         % sample Matlab data
%[y,fs] = audioread(hfile);      % read wav-file

% Define a custom colormap
cmap = [0.4160    0.0350    0.0350;
        0.5620    0.0260    0.0260;
        0.7080    0.0180    0.0180;
        0.7810    0.0130    0.0130;
        0.9270    0.0040    0.0040;
        1.0000         0         0;
        1.0000    0.1410         0;
        1.0000    0.2120         0;
        1.0000    0.3530         0;
        1.0000    0.3880         0;
        1.0000    0.5290         0;
        1.0000    0.5650         0;
        0.9790    0.5480    0.1120;
        0.9570    0.4950    0.2240;
        0.9250    0.4170    0.3920;
        0.9040    0.3650    0.5040;
        0.8710    0.2860    0.6710;
        0.8130    0.2040    0.8160;
        0.7860    0.2010    0.7930;
        0.7060    0.1910    0.7240;
        0.5990    0.1770    0.6320;
        0.4390    0.1570    0.4940];

% Define nfft, window and noverlap
nfft     = 256;
window   = hanning(nfft);
noverlap = round(nfft/2);

% Display the spectrogram of the unfiltered signal
figure;
subplot(3,1,1);
spectrogram(y,window,noverlap,nfft,fs,'yaxis');
colormap(cmap);
title('Unfiltered signal');

% Design and apply the lowpass filter
order = 4;
fg    = 4500;
[b,a] = butter(order,fg/fs/2,'low');             % design filter
x1    = filter(b,a,y);                           % apply filter

% Display the spectrogram of the lowpass filtered signal
subplot(3,1,2);
spectrogram(x1,window,noverlap,nfft,fs,'yaxis');
colormap(cmap);
title('Lowpass filter');

% Design and apply the bandpass filter
order   = 10;
lowfreq = 2000;
hifreq  = 4000;
[b,a]   = butter(order,[lowfreq,hifreq]/(fs/2), 'bandpass'); % design filter
x2      = filter(b,a,y);                                     % apply filter

% Display the spectrogram of the bandpass filtered signal
subplot(3,1,3);
spectrogram(x2,window,noverlap,nfft,fs,'yaxis');
colormap(cmap);
title('Bandpass filter');
```

**It produces the following result:**

[image: Spectrograms]

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm going to give a better example of what is discussed in the comments section. I hope you find this useful. Basically there is a noisy sinusoid signal. I make a spectrogram, and then filter some of the noise away and make another spectrogram to show the result of filtering.

```
x = 0:0.001:4*pi;
y = sin(x);
y2 = wgn(1,length(x),0.5);
y3 = sin(314*x);
y4 = y+y3+y2;

figure(1)
plot(x,y4);

nfft = 2^nextpow2(length(y4));
[S,F,T,P] = spectrogram(y4,250,50,nfft,1000);

figure(2)
spectrogram(y4,250,50,nfft,1000);

%create filter and use it on the noisy signal
[b,a] = butter(4,0.5,'low');
y5 = filtfilt(b,a,y4);

figure(3)
spectrogram(y5,250,50,nfft,1000);
```

Here are the plots generated:

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see the spectrogram call has a default scaling of the colors used, you could alter the colors through the figure handle, which if you want to know how to do that I'd ask another question on SO or google it.

And please heed the advice of Matt in the comments section who warns that you need to be certain of how you want to filter the wav file.